# Estimate inflammability of ABS?

Tags: polymers, heat

I am studying some electrical components and particularly Raspberry Pi 2 official cases. Their manufacturer says that they consists of ABS (Acrylonitrile butadiene styrene) when I ask if their components are inflammable. 
This answer proposes me that their components are inflammable.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylonitrile_butadiene_styrene) about ABS

> Generally ABS would have useful characteristics within a temperature range from −20 to 80 °C

I think I can say little about the inflammability without extra pieces of information about their ABS.

---

How can you estimate how inflammable some ABS is?

Comment: see if this helps: http://fire.nist.gov/bfrlpubs/fire86/art017.html